# Showing the union of two finite set is finite

Tags: real-analysis

(Def) A set $A$ is finite if there is bijection $f: A \to \{1,2,...,n\} = \mathbb{N}_n $

Question: If $A,B$ are finite, then $A \cup B $ must be finite.

Attempt: We have $A = \{ a_1,...,a_k \} $ and $B = \{ b_1,...,b_r \} $. IF we define $f: A\cup B \to \mathbb{N}_{k+r} $ by $f(x_i) = i $ if $x_i \in A$ and $f(x_i) = i + k $ if $x_i \in B $. Is this correct? It seems to me that my proof is imcomplete since I ignore the fact that $A$, $B$ are not necessarily disjoint. would the argument still work ? thanks

Comment: FYI your title is slightly misleading, since it sounds like "$\bigcup A$ is finite if $A$ is finite" which is false. Perhaps "the union of two finite sets is finite"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that your proof only works when $A,B$ are disjoint. However, it is easy to set it up so that you can assume this "without loss of generality": If $A,B$ are finite sets, then $B\setminus A\subseteq B$ is finite and disjoint from $A$, so by your proof $A\cup(B\setminus A)=A\cup B$ is finite.

Comment: Why is it important that $A,B$ are disjoint?  Given a k greater than the size of A (since A is finite), $f(x_i) = i + k$ if $x_i \in B$ will always differ from $f(x_i) = i$ if $x_i \in A$, correct?  You may have duplicate $x_i$'s, but you'll always have a finite total number of them (that is to say, $f$ won't be injective). (Edit: forgive me for how dumb this might sound)

Comment: (edit time ran out: you may have duplicate $x_i$'s, but you'll always have a finite total number of $f(x_i)$'s. That is to say, $f$ won't be injective but I don't think that implies that the codomain is infinite).

Comment: @SubSevn I'm assuming that the OP is trying to construct a bijection between $A\cup B$ and $\{1,\dots,k+n\}$, and the function given only defines an injection (assuming he picks say the $A$ definition in preference to the $B$ definition on the intersection). Of course with a little sophistication you know that this is also good enough, since then the range of $f$ will be a finite set bijective with $A\cup B$.

Comment: I guess my question really boils down to this: how does his proof break down even if $A = B$? It seems like although you may have elements duplicated between $A$ and $B=A$, it won't affect the finite-ness of the codomain of $f$.

Comment: Also, the answer (and my comment) assume that you know a subset of a finite set is finite, which isn't exactly trivial, although you can prove it by induction using the lemma "$A\cup\{b\}$ is finite when $A$ is finite" which can be proven using the original disjoint argument since if $b\in A$ then $A=A\cup\{b\}$ finishes the proof (so there is no circularity).

Comment: @SubSevn If $A=B$, then we define $f(x_i)=i$ if $x_i\in A$ and $f(x_i)=i+k$ if $x_i\in A$, which is not well-defined for any $x_i$. If we pick the first case in preference to the second, then we have a function, alright, but it's not a bijection from $A$ to $\Bbb N_{k+k}$ as we wanted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22606/discussion-between-subsevn-and-mario-carneiro).