# If $A$ and $B$ are finite sets, show that $A \cup B$ is finite

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

If $A$ and $B$ are finite sets, show that $A \cup B$ is finite

I already found the bijection to be 
$h: A \cup B \rightarrow \big\{1,\ldots , n+m \big\}$
$$h(x)= \begin{cases}
f(x),&\text{if }x\in \big\{1,\ldots,n\big\}\\
m+g(x),&\text{if }x\in \big\{n+1,\ldots ,n+m\big\}
\end{cases}$$

here $f$ is a bijection from $A \rightarrow \big\{1,\ldots ,n \big\}$
and g is a bijction from $B \rightarrow \big\{1, \ldots ,m \big\}$

What i'm really asking is how do i show $h(x)$ is onto and one-to-one. Can someone walk me through the steps. Piece wise functions confuse me

Comment: What is $f$ here?

Comment: @aduh 
here $f$ is a bijection from $A \rightarrow \big\{1,\ldots ,n \big\}$
and g is a bijction from $B \rightarrow \big\{1, \ldots ,m \big\}$

Comment: @user46944 : or $g(x)=m+f(x)=m+x$ ?

Comment: The domain of $h$ should be $A \cup B$, right? Not the natural numbers.

Comment: @user46944 yes sorry

Comment: @Nuncameesquecideti That's right.  Do you think something different is meant in the question?

Comment: After cleaning up the typos, you should really try to solve this yourself. Just remind yourself of the definitions of one-to-one and onto.

Comment: @jimmbo Something is still off, I think.  Maybe $h(x)$ should be $n + g(x)$ instead of $m + g(x)$.

Comment: show that h is injective, taking the 2 elements from one set and then from the 2 sets. For surjection, show that you know always find the source

Comment: @aduh thats where im stuck. idk why i cant get piecewise functions when it comes to proving onte/one-to-one

Comment: @jimmbo Are you assuming $A$ and $B$ are disjoint?  If not, your function may not be a bijection.

Comment: yes i am  @user46944

Comment: See this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1222298/showing-the-union-of-two-finite-set-is-finite

Answer (score 2):

I want to suggest proving it in the following way, which I think is less confusing. I'm assuming that $A$ and $B$ are subsets of a single set, in which case $A \cap B$ may not be empty, and the number of elements in $A \cup B$ may not be $m + n$.

1. $A \cup B = (A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A) \cup (A \cap B)$.
2. Subsets of finite sets are finite.
3. Disjoint unions of finite sets are finite.

Comment: $A \cup (B \setminus A)$ would be a bit simpler, I think.

Answer (score 1):

You could argue by induction on the size of the finite set $B$. If $|B|=0$, then $B=\varnothing$. Therefore $A\cup B$ is finite (completing the base case). Now assume that $A\cup B$ is finite for $|B|\le k$. Then you have to show that $A\cup B$ is finite for $|B|=k+1$. [Hint: $B=\{x\}\cup(B\setminus\{x\})$ for some $x\in B$]

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea but you are confusing whether $x \in A \cup B$ or $x \in \mathbb N$.  If $f| A \rightarrow \{1,...., n\}$ then you can't say $x \in  \{1,...., n\}$.  And if $g(x)| \{1,...., m\}\rightarrow B$ then you can't say $h(x) = m + g(x)$ because $g(x)$ is not a number.

Let $f:A \rightarrow \{1...n\}$ be a bijection to $A$, a set with $n$ elements and $g:B\rightarrow\{1....m\}  $ be a bijection to the $m$ elements of $B$.

Let $h:A\cup B\rightarrow \{1...n+m\}$

$h(x) = f(x)$ if $x \in A$.

$h(x) = n + g(x)$ if $x \not \in A$.

Note: the function will *NOT* be a bijection.  It will be injective but it will not be surjective.  This is fine, because have an injective function to a finite set means the set is finite.

Let $h(x) = h(y)$.  If $x \in A$ but $y \not \in A$ (or vice versa) then $h(x) = f(x) \le n$.  $h(y) = n + g(x) > n$.  So $h(x) = h(y)$ only if both $x$ and $y$ are both in $A$ or both not in $A$.

If $x,y \in A$ then $h(x) = f(x)$ and $h(y) = f(y)$. As $f$ is bijection $x = y$.

If $x,y \not \in A$ then $h(x)=n + g(x)$ and $h(y) = n+g(y)$ so $g(x) = g(y)$ and $x = y$ as $g$ is bijection.

So $h$ is an injective map from $A\cup B$ to the finite set $\{1,... n+ m\}$ so $A \cup B$.

postscript: note, if $x \in A \cap B$ and if $f(x) \ne g(x)$, then $h(x) = f(x) \ne g(x)$.  There is no $y \in A \cup B$ so the $h(x) = g(x)$.  So $h$ is not surjective.

Comment: if $x\not\in A$ then why you said that $h(x)=n+g(x)$? I couldn't understand this piece wise function.

Comment: Suppose A={red, yellow, blue, green} we have f(red)=1;f(yellow)=2;f(blue)=3;f(green)=4 so A is finite because f is a bijection to {1,2,3,4}.  And suppose B={blistering, blue, barnacles} and g(blistering);g(blue)=2;g(barnacles)=3 and g is a bijection to {1,2,3}. Then A U B={red,blistering,yellow,blue,green,barnacles} and we want h to map to {1,2,.....,k}. How do we do that? We can say if x in A; h= so h(red)=1;h(yellow)=2;h(blue)=3;h(green)=4. but .... to be continued.

Comment: ...continued... if we say if x in B; h=g and we have h(blistering)=1;h(blue)=2;h(barnacles)=3 then h is not injective as h(red)=h(blistering)=1 and h(green)=h(barnacles)=3.  But we can make it injective by saying. if x in A; h(x)=f(x) and if x in B the h(x) = n+g(x).  So h(red)=1;h(yellow)=2;h(blue)=3;h(green)=4;h(blistering)=5;h(blue)=6;h(barnacles)=7.  That is injective as no two input map to the same output.  But it's not a FUNCTION. But h(blue)=3 and h(blue)=6 and that is not consistant and well define.  if x in A$\cap$B we have a problem.  ... to be continued...

Comment: ... continued... Okay.  we ignore it.  If x in A then h(x)=f(x).  if x in B but x not in A then h(x)=n +g(x). And if x in A$\cap$B then x in A and h(x)=f(x). In this case you have h(red)=1;h(yellow)=2;h(blue)=3;h(green)=4;h(blistering)=5;h(blue)=3;h(barnicles)=7.  h is now an bijective function to {1,2,3,4,5,7} and as {1,2,3,4,5,7} is a subset of {1,2,3,4,5,6,7} h is an injective function *into* {1,2,3,4,5,6,7} and so A U B is finite.  "But wait" someone cries "h(x)=6 doesn't exist". That's okay. h is not *bi*jective.  But it doesn't need to be to be finite. Injective is good enough.